# How to get rid of light desktop manager entry in Ubuntu greeter

Tags: 13.10, unity-greeter

I've got a "light desktop manager" entry in Ubuntu greeter for some strange reason, and I can't get rid of it. As the current OS is Ubuntu 13.10 the way to configure the lightdm greeter is rather strange, and I can't find any solution in greeter configs.

A more annoying thing is that LDM seems to have password very hard to guess so I can't login to this "account".

Can you help me to find what is causing this problem and find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Is a bug though some users report it's stopped thru some post release updates
(I can still recreate as orig. described

Report here, if still affected then there is a workaround or 2 in the comments

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1235785